# What's the proper way to handle localized name-spaced routes in Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, routes, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm localizing my application and am struggling with how to handle routes for a specific portion of the app.

Initially I had routes that looked like this:

```
    map.namespace :admin do |admin|
      admin.resources :people, :member => {:confirm_destroy => :get}, :collection => {:follow => :post, :sync_friends => :get, :upload => :post, :import => :get, :recommendations => :get, :mark_recommendations => :post, :batch_create => :post}
      admin.resources :jobs, :collection => {:remove => :post}
      admin.resources :users, :member => {:confirm_destroy => :get}
      admin.resources :sites, :member => {:update_design => :post, :design => :get, :update_links => :post, :links => :get, :content => :get, :update_content => :post, :add_admin => :post, :remove_admin => :post, :set_system_account => :get, :confirm_system_account => :get}, :collection => {:remove => :post, :upload => :post}
      admin.resources :subscriptions, :member => { :charge => :post, :migrate_plan => :post, :update_components => :post }
      admin.resources :accounts, :collection => {:remove => :post}
      admin.resources :subscription_plans, :as => 'plans'
      admin.resources :subscription_discounts, :as => 'discounts'
      admin.resources :twitter_lists, :collection => {:auto_generate_twitter_list => :post}
    end
```

From what I've done successfully on other routes I need to add: `:path_prefix => '/:locale/'` to these routes.

The only example I've come across looks something like this: 

  `map.with_options(:path_prefix => '/:locale/admin') do |locale|
    locale.namespace :admin do |admin|
      admin.resources :people, :member => {:confirm_destroy => :get}, :collection => {:follow => :post, :sync_friends => :get, :upload => :post, :import => :get, :recommendations => :get, :mark_recommendations => :post, :batch_create => :post}
      admin.resources :subscriptions, :member => { :charge => :post, :migrate_plan => :post, :update_components => :post }
      admin.resources :accounts, :collection => {:remove => :post}
      etc etc etc
    end
  end`

This actually appears works great for the routes, however, it is screwing up some of my generated URLS.

For example previously I had something like `= link_to(t('subscription'), edit_admin_subscription_path(subscription_id)` which worked perfectly... after the above change this url no longer properly generates, giving the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Admin/base#index

Showing app/views/admin/shared/_menu.html.haml where line #13 raised:

edit_admin_subscription_url failed to generate from {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/subscriptions", :locale=>BSON::ObjectId('4d0ecb6587adddc91c000014')}, expected: {:controller=>"admin/subscriptions", :action=>"edit"}, diff: {:locale=>BSON::ObjectId('4d0ecb6587adddc91c000014')}
```

**I would sincerely appreciate any insight anyone can shed on the proper way to handle this type of thing and/or why this url doesn't like to generate any longer. THANKS!**

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out after the addition of the localization, I needed to be more specific with the the parameters passed into the URL helper:

`= link_to(t('subscription'), edit_admin_subscription_path(:id => subscription_id)` works just fine.

Still not sure not certain if the

```
  map.with_options(:path_prefix => '/:locale/admin') do |locale|
    locale.namespace :admin do |admin|
```

is the best way to do that, but at least it's working for now.